# For which values of $x,y$ does $x^2+y^2$ take the minimum?

Tags: calculus

> Find the values of $x,y$ for which $x^2+y^2$ takes the minimum value where $(x+5)^2+(y-12)^2=14^2$.

Trial:$\begin{align} \ (x+5)^2+(y-12)^2=14^2 \\ \implies x^2+y^2+10x-24y=27 \end{align}$.

Here I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: I'd love to see this solved using AM GM inequality as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about Lagrange's Multipliers? Let

$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2\,\,,\,\,g(x,y)=(x+5)^2+(y-12)^2-14^2\Longrightarrow$$

$$H(x,y,\lambda)=f+\lambda g=x^2+\lambda(x+5)^2+y^2+\lambda(y-12)^2-14^2\Longrightarrow$$

$$H'_x=2\left((x+\lambda(x+5)\right)=0\Longrightarrow x=-\frac{5\lambda}{1+\lambda}$$

$$H'_y=2\left(y+\lambda(y-12)\right)=0\Longrightarrow y=\frac{12\lambda}{1+\lambda}$$

$$H'_\lambda=(x+5)^2+(y-12)^2-14^2\Longrightarrow H'_\lambda=g(x,y)=0$$

Substituting the values for $\,x,y\,$ in the last equation above, we get:

$$\left(-\frac{5\lambda}{1+\lambda}+5\right)^2+\left(\frac{12\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)^2=14^2\Longrightarrow (25+144)\frac{1}{(1+\lambda)^2}=14^2\Longrightarrow$$

$$(1+\lambda)^2=\frac{13^2}{14^2}\Longrightarrow 1+\lambda =\pm\frac{13}{14}$$

Try now to take it from here.

Comment: $1+\lambda=+\frac{13}{14}$ gives us the minimum value of $x^2+y^2$ right? Can we discern it w/o actual testing? Also, the 2nd line should end with $14^2\lambda?$

Comment: It's obvious that we have to take the value that makes both $\,x,y\,$ the smallest in absolute value, and that indeed happens with $$\lambda=-\frac{1}{14}\,\Longrightarrow x=\frac{5}{13}\,,\,y=-\frac{12}{13}$$

Answer (score 4):

Think of it geometrically. You have a point $P$ inside a circle, and you want to find the point on the circle closest to $P$. So, you draw a ray from the center of the circle to/through $P$, and see where that ray intersects the circle.

Answer (score 4):

We can also look at this geometrically:

Letting $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, we see that each value of $x^2 + y^2$ corresponds to a circle of a different radius, centered at the origin. If we construct the smallest such circle which intersects a circle of radius $14$ centered at $(-5,12)$, the point of intersection will give us our $(x,y)$. A little thought will convince you that the smaller circle will be tangent to the larger circle at this point, so that there is only one solution. But since those circles are tangent, that point will lie on the line connecting their centers (where both circles intersect that line.)

Comment: +1 This is a very nice, pretty basic, geometric and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

So, $x=14\cos t-5,y=14\sin t+12$

So, $x^2+y^2=(14\cos t-5)^2+(14\sin t+12)^2=14^2+5^2+12^2+28(12\sin t-5\cos t)$

So, we need to maximize $12\sin t-5\cos t$

(1) Let $g(t)=12\sin t-5\cos t$

$g'(t)=12\cos t+5\sin t$

For the extremem values of  $g(t), g'(t)=0\implies \frac{\cos t}5=\frac{\sin t}{-12}=\pm\frac{\sqrt {\sin^2t+\cos^2t}}{\sqrt {5^2+(-12)^2}}=\pm\frac1{13}$

$g''(t)=-12\sin t+5\cos t$

If $\cos t=\frac5{13},\sin t=-\frac{12}{13}, g''(t)>0$ then $g(t)$ will have the minimum value.

If $\cos t=-\frac5{13},\sin t=\frac{12}{13}, g''(t)<0$ then $g(t)$ will have the maximum value.

(2) Let $R=12\sin t-5\cos t--->(1)$

Squaring $(R+5\cos t)^2=(12\sin t)^2=144(1-\cos^2t)$

or $169\cos^2t+10R\cos t+R^2-144=0$

As $\cos t$ is real, $(-10R)^2-4\cdot169(R^2-144)=576(169-R^2)$ must be $\ge 0$

So, $R^2\le 169, R\le 13$

So, the maximum value of $R(=12\sin t-5\cos t)$ is $13$
$ \iff(13\cos t+5)^2=0\implies\cos t=-\frac5{13}$

Putting the values of $R,\cos t$ in $(1),\sin t=\frac{12}{13}$

(3)Put $12=r\cos u,5=r\sin u$ where $r>0$

so that  $12^2+5^2=(r\cos u)^2+(r\sin u)^2\implies r^2=169\implies r=13, \cos u=\frac{12}{13},\sin u=\frac5{13}$

Putting the values of $R,\cos t$ in $(1)$ we get $\sin t=\frac{12}{13}$

$12\sin t-5\cos t=r\sin(t-u)=13\sin(t-u)\le 13$ for real $u,t$

Clearly,  $12\sin t-5\cos t($ hence, $x^2+y^2)$ will maximized if $\sin(t-u)=1$

So, $t-u=2n\pi+\frac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer.

So, $\cos t=\cos(2n\pi+\frac\pi2+u)=-\sin u=-\frac5{13}$

So, $\sin t=\sin(2n\pi+\frac\pi2+u)=\cos u=\frac{12}{13}$

So, $x=14\cos t-5=14(-\frac5{13})-5=-\frac{135}{13}$

and $y=14\sin t+12=14(\frac{12}{13})+12=\frac{324}{13}$

---

Alternatively, using [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier),

$$F(x,y)=x^2+y^2+\lambda((x+5)^2+(y-12)^2-14^2)$$

Applying partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y,$

$0=F_x=2x+2\lambda(x+5)$ and $0=F_y=2y+2\lambda(y-12)$

Express $x,y$ in terms of $\lambda$ and put their values in the given condition to find $\lambda$ and hence $x,y.$

Comment: watch the denominator of $\,x\,$: it must be $\,13\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks for identifying the typo.